# I am getting some issue while inserting data to mongodb atlas using node js. Can someone please help me in resolving this?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-atlas-search

After connecting with mongodb atlas, I am getting some issue while inserting data in mongodb atlas. Here is my node code where i insert routing code of insertion.

I am getting this error

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAXnb.png)

app.js

[app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgFM5.png)

And following is the code where i inserted the data

[Data.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECsLx.png)

Comment: Seems , Mongodb connection issue

Comment: You can't use Axios to make MongoDB queries.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hey Yatin, welcome to Stack Overflow. Maybe you should remove your password from the screenshot.